# Adding libaries programmatically to referenced libaries

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am currently working on my own project wizard plugin for eclipse. It is working only thing I am having problems with is the library gets set to the class path and looks like this.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujLKU.png)

I am trying to get it to show up in the referenced libraries folder like it does when you add external jar via the Java Build Path menu. This is my current attempt, adding the library to the class path which makes it appear in the `src` folder.

```
private void addProjectLibrary(IJavaProject project, File lib) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException, CoreException {
    // copy the jar file into the project
    InputStream jarLibraryInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(lib));
    IFile libFile = project.getProject().getFile(lib.getName());
    libFile.create(jarLibraryInputStream, false, ipm);

    // create a classpath entry for the library
    IClasspathEntry relativeLibraryEntry = new org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClasspathEntry(
        IPackageFragmentRoot.K_BINARY,
        IClasspathEntry.CPE_LIBRARY, libFile.getLocation(),
        ClasspathEntry.INCLUDE_ALL, // inclusion patterns
        ClasspathEntry.EXCLUDE_NONE, // exclusion patterns
        null, null, null, // specific output folder
        false, // exported
        ClasspathEntry.NO_ACCESS_RULES, false, // no access rules to combine
        ClasspathEntry.NO_EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES);

    // add the new classpath entry to the project's existing entries
    IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = project.getRawClasspath();
    IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);
    newEntries[oldEntries.length] = relativeLibraryEntry;
    project.setRawClasspath(newEntries, ipm);
}
```

Comment: Instead of instantiating an *internal* ClasspathEntry instance yourself, try using the `JavaCore#newLibraryEntry()` method.

Comment: Just tried that it does add a little referenced libs icon to the jar but it is still not under the Referenced Libraries folder.

Comment: What's the project's `.classpath` file look like before and after?

Comment: Before: https://pastebin.com/eQMiLb0y
After:  https://pastebin.com/iAnfNM39